# Excel VBA, find out minimum value under same group of data

Tags: vba, excel

I want ask if there is anyway to write a VBA that can return value in column C which have the minimum value in column B under the same group in Column A

For example, for the following table, the output should return Strawberry for Race A, Orange for Race B and Grapes for Race C.

```
Col A  |  Col B  |  Col C       
Race A |   12    |  Orange         
Race B |   13    |  Apple     
Race A |   9     |  Strawberry       
Race B |   7     |  Orange     
Race C |   12    |  Strawberry     
Race B |   10    |  Cherry     
Race C |   5     |  Grapes
```

Comment: I think you mean Column D (since Column C has values inside it). You are looking for a UDF ? or what ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Column A, B, C are the raw data as stated above. I want to get the output in another column (e.g.put the result in Column D to Column E,  Cell D1 = Race A, Cell E1 = Strawberry, Cell D2 = Race B, Cell E2 = Orange, Cell D3 = Race C, Cell E3 = Grapes)

Comment: @AAA It is possible to do it without VBA (I am VBA coder but this case can be handled with functions directly). If you are interested then I can answer. If you certainly want to know how to accomplish that with VBA then not necessary.

Comment: yes I'm interested. can you show me how to accomplish it? thanks!

Comment: Excel 2016 has the `MINIFS` function https://exceljet.net/formula/minimum-if-multiple-criteria

Comment: @AAA have you tried any of the solutions you got ? any feedback ?

Comment: @AAA we don't get notified in the comments if you don't mention the name of the user that you are replying. I posted my formulate solution. Please check it out as you really don't need VBA to do this unless you specifically want VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I did not play with it a lot, there should be exceptions probably, but it works on your example:

`=MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$7=A12;$B$1:$B$7));$B$1:$B$7;0)`

Array formulas are entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function:

```
Function GetFruit(race As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If .item(cell.Value) = "" Then
                .item(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(, 1) & "|" & cell.Offset(, 2).Address
            ElseIf cell.Offset(, 1).Value < CInt(Split(.item(cell.Value), "|")(0)) Then
                .item(cell.Value) = cell.Offset(, 1) & "|" & cell.Offset(, 2).Address
            End If
        Next cell
        GetFruit = Split(.item(race), "|")(0)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below (VBA solution) is placed in your `Worksheet_Change` event (in your worksheet where you have your data).
Once you modify a value in Column D, the code searches for the minimum value at Column B that matches criteria in your post.

It returns the result to Column E

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long, RowFound As Long
Dim MinVal, Rng As Range, cell As Range

' run this code once you modify a value in Column D
If Target.Column = 4 Then
    ' find last row with data in Column A
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' set range
    Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

    MinVal = 100000 ' init value of MinVal

    ' loop through all cells in Range and look for minimum value
    For Each cell In Rng.Cells
        If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value Then
            If cell.Value < MinVal Then
                MinVal = cell.Value
                RowFound = cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Error handling : if there was no match with tha value entered in Column D
    If MinVal = 100000 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = "Race value not found"
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Cells(RowFound, 3)
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of the worksheet after running this code a few times (in Column E):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your range is as you provided. You can name the range instead fixed one as in my sample:

Formulas in E column are array formulas: 
Sample for Race A (D1) copy and paste the formula in E1 cell below and while you are still in the cell hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula.

```
D         | E
--------
Race A    | =INDEX(C2:C8,MATCH(D1&MIN(IF(A2:A8=D1,B2:B8)),A2:A8&B2:B8,0))
Race B    | =INDEX(C2:C8,MATCH(D2&MIN(IF(A2:A8=D2,B2:B8)),A2:A8&B2:B8,0))
Race C    | =INDEX(C2:C8,MATCH(D3&MIN(IF(A2:A8=D3,B2:B8)),A2:A8&B2:B8,0))
```